# should assign `nullptr` to `std::unique_ptr` before assigning a new value to it?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<int> ptrA = std::make_unique<int>(10);

    ptrA = std::make_unique<int>(20); // case I

    return 0;
}


#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<int> ptrA = std::make_unique<int>(10);

    ptrA = nullptr;                  // case II or ptrA.reset()
    ptrA = std::make_unique<int>(20);

    return 0;
}
```

I have seen many people use `Case II`. However, `std::unique_ptr` is a smart pointer, I don't think we should assign either `nullptr` or call `reset` before reassigning a new value to it.

Please correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: Why are you assigning std::make_unique<int>(10) to ptrA, then one line later std::make_unique<int>(20) when you can just do *ptrA = 20 - or even shorter: just do ptrA = std::make_unique<int>(20) and be done with it? Or, give some more context to the question?

Comment: @stijn because this code is only to explain idea, not real code.

Comment: @stijn, considering we are writing an assignment operator, one of the member is unique_ptr.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assigning first to `nullptr` is superflous as well as misleading, doing just:

```
ptrA = std::make_unique<int>(20);
```

is sufficient since before the assignment the [`unique_ptr::operator=`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D) will release its owned memory before acquiring its new one.

Comment: Actually if you are calling `std::make_unique` it might make sense to use the assignment in this way. Although I guess the distinction is more important for `std::make_shared`. If you are assigning to a pointer you are completely correct though.

Comment: @101010 what is the potential problem, if we use Case I instead.

Comment: @q0987: You create an extra temporary to hold the result of the `std::make_unique` call potentially (it is then moved into `ptrA` so it might be elided but no guarantee).

Comment: @Slava I hope it does now.

Answer (score 7):

Assigning `nullptr` before assigning a new value is pointless.

Comment: Worse than pointless - it reduces signal-to-noise ratio, and as such, is harmful.

Answer (score 2):

I'd thought calling reset or assigning nullptr would've been pointless, but it turns out this causes smaller footprint in the assembler. The compiler explorer at https://godbolt.org/ with gcc 7.2 and with -O3 the code:

```
void test1()
{
    auto test1 = std::make_unique<int>(5);
    test1 = std::make_unique<int>(6);
}
```

Surprisingly causes more instructions than the uglier version:

```
void test2()
{
    auto test1 = std::make_unique<int>(5);
    test1 = nullptr;
    test1 = std::make_unique<int>(6);
}
```